# making a plugin that moves other plugins wp_head actions to wp_footer

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, mobile, wp-head, footer

I am grappling with implimenting jQm on wordpress and have hit the obstacle that most plugins dont work on jQm ajax loaded pages.

However, taking the example of the sharethis plugin, I have found that it will run on the ajax loaded page if I change this

```
add_action('wp_head', 'st_widget_head');
```

to this

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'st_widget_head');
```

in the sharethis.php file

The thing is that I want to try and do this leaving the initial plugin files untouched (so that wp updates will work and so that I can keep all my jQm specific plugin modification changes in one place- so they can all be turned off if jQm is turned off)

So I think what I n eed to make to begin with is a plugin that loads last, that moves any plugins I specify to move their add_action wp_head to add_action wp_footer.

I appreciate this is currently a very brute force solution, but so far this is the only chink of light I have found in what seems to be an impenetrable situation, which otherwise requires re-writing all the plugins I use to work with jQm.

So any ideas on this would be very helpful in helping me create a more solid and maintainable solution to this, something like a 'jQm plugin fixer plugin' that I and the community could develop and maintain...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the action, then add it back on a different hook.

I think the only concern you could have with doing this is ensuring you do that late enough for the action to have been hooked, it should possible using the `plugins_loaded` hook(because that runs after plugins have loaded).

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'juggle_sharethis_action' );

function juggle_sharethis_action() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'st_widget_head' );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'st_widget_head' );
}
```

Actions
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Adding actions
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Removing actions
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Comment: Fantastic, I'll try that. Thanks so much for your quick response and the extra info. I'll keep this updated with my progress...

Comment: You're welcome, let me know how you get on.